# Do shortcode that is inserted in a textarea is not displaying properly

Tags: shortcode

In the dashboard, I'm using a textarea to get user input. I'd like them to be able to use shortcodes anywhere in that textarea.

Here's my current function:

```
function slp_getwelcome() {                 
    $slp_welcome = get_option('slp_welcome');   
    $slp_welcome_sc = do_shortcode( $slp_welcome );

    return $slp_welcome_sc;     
}
```

This partially works.

If I have this text in the textarea:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur [location] adipiscing elit. Donec sit
>   amet quam id eros fringilla.

The above function outputs this:

> Abbott, CALorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit
>   amet quam id eros fringilla.

Where "Abbott, CA" is the proper result of the `[location]` shortcode. So the shortcode is called, but it returns at the beginning of the textarea content.

How can I fix this?

Here's the shortcode logic:

```
function get_location() { 
    global $post;
    $location = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'locations', '', ', ', '' ) );
    echo $location; 
} 
add_shortcode('location', 'get_location');
```

A second shortcode reacting the same, despite the use of `return`:

```
function get_service() { 
    $servive = single_post_title() ;
    return $service;
} 
add_shortcode('service', 'get_service');
```

Comment: I think you need to show your shortcode logic.

Comment: @vancoder shortcode function has been added to the original post

Comment: Any particular reason this post was down voted? --So I can try to avoid that mistake in the future.

Comment: Haven't down-voted it, but probably it's because this is a common mistake easily found searching this site archives. That's the only flaw I can see, all in all, the Q is well explained, documented and formated, keep'em coming ;)

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo. I'll keep that in mind in my future questions and responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be `return`ing $location from `get_location`, instead of `echo`ing it. Your function currently echos the location as soon as it runs, thereby outputting the result before the rest of the copy.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I'm still learning all the ins and outs of PHP, but this makes sense now.

Comment: I have two different shortcodes that might be called in this textarea. I changed both to `return` instead of `echo`, however my second shortcode reacts the same as what was described in the original post. The original post has been updated to show the second shortcode.

Comment: start reading the corresponding Codex chapter when you are using a WordPress function - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_post_title

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I used that codex to get that function intially, but I read it further and realized using `single_post_title('', false)` actually output the title to be used properly for the shortcode. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to return your value, instead of echoing it.

```
function hello() {
    return '{foobar}';
}

add_shortcode('hw', 'hello');
```